# Python 3. Обозначение переменных внутри строк, которые хранятся, например в словаре или списке

Tags: python, json, переменные, вывод, хранение-данных

Я начал делать поддержку мультиязычности для свой программы, и возник вопрос хранения переменных внутри сообщений - строк.

При выводе строки происходит подстановка переменной, строки хранятся в словаре конкретного языка. То есть например у меня есть словарь, я вывожу строку по ключу, а в этой строке должны вызываться переменные которые я должен вывести, как бы вставить на нужные мне места внутри этой строки.

Надеюсь правильно и понятно описал суть вопроса. Переменная чаще всего приходит например из функции при ее вызове, и далее должна происходить подстановку в строку.

P.S. у меня в программе данные хранятся в *JSON* соответственно при выводе совершается `encode` *JSON* в *Python* данные.

Comment: Вариант `'Hello, {name}'.format(name='Andrew')` не подходит?

Comment: Вам нужно подставить значения в строку, которая в формате JSON?

Comment: на DJANGO перейти не пробовали?

Comment: Вообщем решил вопрос gettext, мой пример.. https://github.com/notariuss/locale